# Using subfactorial in algebra

Tags: combinatorics, factorial

Can someone explain the real use of subfactorial?  I know that factorial and subfactorial are related to each other, but they function differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subfactorial is useful in calculating the number of *derangements*, i.e., the number of permutation of $n$ objects in which none of them remain in their original position.  For instance, one derangement of $ABCDEF$ is $BADCFE$.  (The permutation $BADECF$ is *not* a derangement of $ABCDEF$ because $F$ remains in the last position.)

The number of derangements of $n$ objects is:

$$!n = (n-1)(!(n-1) + !(n-2)) ,$$

where $!n$ is read "$n$ subfactorial."

For $n = 1, \ldots , 10$ the values are $\{0, 1, 2, 9, 44, 265, 1854, 14833, 133496, 1334961 \}$.

For the $n=6$ case of $ABCDEF$, we find $!n = 265$.